# How to handle concurrent save in a Sale Website, while RDS database is upgrading?

Tags: amazon-web-services, concurrency, amazon-rds, amazon-sqs

I'm implementing a low-cost architecture in AWS that I have an RDS database with Multi-AZ to handle failure and I have a website of sales. I implemented a Cloudwatch to monitor the use of the database and if is reaching the limit, it triggers a lambda to upgrade the instance type of the RDS to handle the new incomes requests in the RDS.
But the problem is, even with the Multi-AZ, which has an new instance to handle requests while the main database is off when the upgrade is running there is a time that you can't connect into the database for like 2 ~ 3 minutes.

Reference -> https://medium.com/funambol-techblog/managing-auto-scaling-of-rds-on-aws-using-the-aws-cli-and-bash-9b1aa970ade3

(Even with a Multi-AZ RDS deployment, the failover of an RDS instance introduces DNS changes and up to 2–3 minutes of unavailability of the database.)

I didn't want to implement a high-cost architecture with cache or a new database, so I tried to implement an SQS to keep the requests that failed to connect with the database waiting 2~3 minutes until the upgrade finished.

But the problem is if Client A tries to buy product A, and the database is Down, it should go to the SQS to wait until the upgrade is finished. But if Client B tries to buy the same product and is quicker to reach the database, when Client A got out of the SQS it would not buy his product.

Is there any concurrency technique to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't this should be done on the database level, this should be done in the queue and in your application to make sure transactions are played to the database in the right order! There is no way a database can anticipate that there may be a pending transaction later, that could voic the current transaction!

Comment: @Shadow, I agree it should be in-app level. But how should I do that without increasing the queue, digging a bigger hole? Because I could control the new requests inserting in the queue, but it would be an infinite queue.

Comment: I do not know - I retagged your question to get people familiar with AWS and SQS involved as opposed to database people, like myself.